# Automatically copy contents of FTP folder to local Windows folder without overwrite?

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I need to copy all the files of an FTP folder to my local Windows folder, but without replacing the files that already exist. This would need to be a job/task that runs unattended every hour.

This is what the job would need to do:
1. Connect to FTP server.
2. In ftp, move to folder /var/MyFolder.
3. In local PC, move to c:\MyDestination.
4. Copy all files in /var/MyFolder that do not exist in c:\MyDestination.
5. Disconnect.

I had previously tried the following script using **MGET *** (that runs from a .bat), but it copies and overwrites everything. Which means that even if 1000 files were previously copied, it will copy them again.

```
open MyFtpServer.com
UserName
Password
lcd c:\MyDestination
cd /var/MyFolder
binary
mget *
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wget for Windows](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/).

If you want to include subdirectories *(adjust the `cut-dirs` number according to the depth of your actual remote path)*:

```
cd /d C:\MyDestination
wget.exe --mirror -np -nH --cut-dirs=2 ftp://UserName:Password@MyFtpServer.com/var/MyFolder
```

If you don't want subdirectories:

```
cd /d C:\MyDestination
wget.exe -nc ftp://UserName:Password@MyFtpServer.com/var/MyFolder/*
```

The "magic" bit (for this second form) is the `-nc` option, which tells `wget` not to overwrite files that are already there locally. Do keep in mind that old files are also left alone, so if a file on your FTP server gets edited or updated, it won't get re-downloaded. If you want to also update files, use `-N` instead of `-nc`.

*(Note that you can also type `wget` instead of `wget.exe`, I just included the extension to point out that these are Windows batch file commands)*

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

It works somewhat, but I found a few problems:
1) My default folder when I log on is /home/jdoe; the folder I will copy from isn't inside this folder. How can I move to /var/MyFolder?

2) Why did you add "-d" switch in cd? I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." The reason I ask is that I won't be copying the files to the current folder, I have to copy them to a specific folder.

Comment: You can use the `-P` flag of `wget` to specify a target directory.

Comment: Let's say I'm running WGET from a Windows PC at E:\MyDestination. Is it possible to use -P flag to copy the contents into E:\MyOtherFolder\MyCustomFolder? I assume it's only to copy to targets with HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Edited. Habit of Linux command lines; the correct parameter is `/d`, not `-d` - and it makes `cd` have effect even if you are currently on a different letter. And yes, wget is only for copying from a remote server, if you need to copy local files use `copy` or `xcopy`.